# Modifying the contents of a structure through a void pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, void

Note that I'm 95% unfamiliar with pointers.

So here's my dilemma, I have a structure let's call it `foo`

```
struct foo{
int a;
}
```

so let's create an instance of foo

```
foo test;
```

Now I want to assign a void pointer to point to this

```
 void *ptest;
 ptest = &test;
```

This all works great, but when it comes to modifying the contents (ie int a within foo), I'm not sure how to approach this. I tried `static_cast` like this:

```
static_cast<foo*>(ptest).a=0;
```

but that didn't work either. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: seeing someone using `static_cast` with no knowledge of `->` just brainwashed me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're casting it to a pointer, thus you need to dereference it using the `*` operator or use the `->` operator.

Option A:

```
*(static_cast<foo*>(ptest)).a=0
```

Option B:

```
static_cast<foo*>(ptest)->a=0
```

Comment: Holy... lordy. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 2):

You simply have to replace . with ->

You use the dot operator when dealing with the object directly or a reference of it, and the -> operator when you deal with it through a pointer.